# Read the values with knowing ColumnFamily and Column qualifier with thrift in a hbase dataset

Tags: hbase, thrift

How can I just read the rows, with a specific ColumnFamily and Column Qualifier?

So, I know, ColumnFamily = "R" and Column = "r000003vl_*". How can I get all the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make scan for only column family R and column value filter with "r000003vl_*", this will return all rows' that column data if row has the column key value.

Comment: how make that scan? which function can I use?

Answer (score -1):

use ColumnPrefixFilter to scan column family R.

https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/ColumnPrefixFilter.html

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks